# Headers sent in curl request from php are working on one server and not on another

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I have a weird problem, sending curl request with headers from one server abc.com to another server xyz.com are working while they are not working with another server xyz1.com and its not a subdomain.

I am getting 400 bad request error from xyz1.com server.

Can you help me to get clue what needs to be added to curl request code or need to change in server settings?

Comment: Could you provide an exemple of request with header? Does xyz1 got the same webserver and conf that xyz?

Comment: Please provide code examples and environmental details. `php -m | grep curl` from each machine would be a good start as well.